# get a list into a string

Tags: python, string, list

```
filename = 'result'
column = 'Latitude'

os.system("wget http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/csv/1.0/hour")
#csv_data = csv.reader(downloaded_data)

file = csv.reader(open('/home/coperthought/Documents/hour' , 'rb'), delimiter='\t')

data = [] # This will contain our data

# Create a csv reader object to iterate through the file
reader = csv.reader( open( '/home/coperthought/Documents/hour' , 'rU'), delimiter=',', dialect='excel')

hrow = reader.next() # Get the top row
idx = hrow.index(column) # Find the column of the data you're looking for

for row in reader: # Iterate the remaining rows
    data.append( row[idx] )


os.remove ( '/home/coperthought/Documents/hour')
print data
```

then data is

```
['63.190', '63.730', '59.935', '38.805', '61.416', '63.213']
```

how can I get this into a string.  Join is one..

thanks

Comment: And welcome to stackoverflow. Please use the editor's format option to put your code into a readable question.

Comment: It would help your cause if you explained what you have tried and how or why it did not work

Comment: What is "this"? If it's the `print` output, you get it with `str(data)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not obvious what you want, what you have and how you expect to get there with what you've done. Please **give example input and output** needed and *explain* what you've been trying to do to achieve this.

Comment: thank you for your replies!  First off I am quite new in this world of Python.  I am trying to post a status into Facebook, all it allows me to do is to post a string as it will not concatenate a list plus a string.  I am trying to learn this language and to put it into a practical scenario.

Comment: I think I got it with str(data)  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> how can I get this into a string. Join is one..

Just use `'whateveryouwanthere'.join(data)`.
You already mentioned the `join` method, you need to explain what's the problem here if you do not want a solution involving `join`.